# Concurrent API requests with https module results in sporadic ETIMEDOUT errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I'm making a bunch of calls, and due to the number of retries I've counted 16981 calls to our third party API. There shouldn't be more than 1000-1500 calls total, so the overwhelming majority of these are probably retries. Very early on I get a 409 back, so my request code retries, which I think causes a cascading problem. After enough calls I hit a ETIMEDOUT error, so I retry again, which is sucking up a ton of execution time.

My ulimit is 4864, so I don't know if that's low enough for it to be the problem.

How can I refactor my code to handle concurrency better and avoid these constant retries? I'm still learning and not sure what a good approach to fix this would be.

Here's my request code:

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https');
const Url = require('url');
const util = require('util');

function createRequest(requestUrl, body, requestHeaders, type = 'GET') {
    // Creates a post request at url with the given body

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const retry = function() {
            // console.log('retrying...');
            createRequest(requestUrl, body, requestHeaders, type);
        }

        const parsedUrl = Url.parse(requestUrl, true, true);
        const options = {
            hostname: parsedUrl.hostname,
            path: parsedUrl.path,
            method: type,
            headers: requestHeaders
        };
        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            // console.log("Retry after: ", res.headers.date);
            let responseString = '';

            res.on('data', (dataChunk) => {
                responseString += dataChunk;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(responseString);
                } else if (res.statusCode === 409) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        return resolve(createRequest(requestUrl, body, requestHeaders, type));
                    }, res.headers['retry-after'] * 1000);
                }
            });
        });

        if (type === 'POST') {
            req.write(JSON.stringify(body));
        }

        req.on('error', (error) => {
            if (error.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
                //console.log('Encountered ETIMEDOUT. Retrying call...');
                console.log('MError: ', util.inspect(error, { showHidden: true, depth: 2 }));

                setTimeout(function() {
                    return resolve(createRequest(requestUrl, body, requestHeaders, type));
                }, 1000);
            }
            // reject(error);
        });

        req.end();
    });
}

module.exports = {
    createRequest
};
```

And the error:

```
MError:  { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.49.220.252:443
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
  [message]: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 52.49.220.252:443',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '52.49.220.252',
  port: 443 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is timing out then you can increase the timeout but `https.request()` doesn't provide an option for the same. You can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module for the same and set an upper value of timeout. Try out and let me know.